# 2d creature images hybridization algorithm

Tags: actionscript-3, 2d, genetic-algorithm, hybrid, morphing

I would like to mutate two monsters in my game to make a simple hybrid. Each monster is a 2d image witch i could implement as composite sprites (to know more about each body parts). The problem is that not all monster is similar types, not all of them is humanoid or any kind of animal. I think for example if we have a lion with 4 legs and the spider with 8 (as example spider gens dominate) it could be the 8 legs lion with other (hybrid between two) color. But if i would have some humanoid and frog what should algorithm do? Any idea or any useful algorithm that could help me?

Comment: Animation? Why don't you just animate it? :)
But you can use ColorMatrixFilter.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement simple genetic system. E.g. have each creature represented by array of values instructing your script what to do in order to create the character: [add_red_human_torso, add_blue_frog_left_leg, .... ]. Then you could take random mix of two creatures arrays and build new creature from that.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving attributes to each of the animals limbs, (Strength for lions legs, jumping for frogs legs, height for human torso, camoflauge for spider color,etc.) and then do a multi objective optimization algorithm.